# How to register an 'unselected' event handler in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

How to register an object related event handler in Fabric.js that fires when user unselects object?

Here we register an `selected` event handler to text object and try to register an `unselected` handler:

```
text = new fabric.Text("Text", {fontFamily: 'Arial'});
text.on("selected", function()
{
  console.log("Text field is selected.");
});
text.on("unselected", function()
{
  console.log("Text field selection is cleared");
});
```

However `unselected` handler doesn't work. Either `cleared` or `selection:cleared` doesn't work.

I don't want to use canvas related event `selection:cleared`, but attach event directly to object.

[Object documentation](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html) doesn't provide answer.